# Is there a way to rename the uploaded file without saving it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, memorystream

I tried looking into `other solutions`, however they suggest either:

1. to `save the file` with a different name with `saveAs()`
2. to change the file name `once the file is saved` with `Move()` or `Copy()`

In my case `I need to rename it without saving it`. I tried changing the `file.FileName` property, however it is `ReadOnly`.

The result I'm trying to get is:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase renameFiles(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    //change the name of the file
    //return same file or its copy with a different name
}
```

It would be `good to have` `HttpPostedFileBase` as a `return type`, however it `can be sacrificed` if needed.

Is there a way to do this through `memory streams` or anything else? I appreciate any help, thank you for taking your time to read this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found a way that's really simple - I guess I was overthinking this a bit. I figured I'll just share the solution, since some of you might need it. I tested it and it works for me.

You just have to `create your own class` `HttpPostedFileBaseDerived` that inherits from `HttpPostedFileBase`. The only difference between them is that you can make a constructor there.

```
    public class HttpPostedFileBaseDerived : HttpPostedFileBase
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBaseDerived(int contentLength, string contentType, string fileName, Stream inputStream)
        {
            ContentLength = contentLength;
            ContentType = contentType;
            FileName = fileName;
            InputStream = inputStream;
        }
        public override int ContentLength { get; }

        public override string ContentType { get; }

        public override string FileName { get; }

        public override Stream InputStream { get; }

        public override void SaveAs(string filename) { }

    }
}
```

Since `constructor is not affected by ReadOnly`, you can easily `copy in the values from your original file` object `to` your `derived class's instance`, while putting your new name in as well:

```
HttpPostedFileBase renameFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string newFileName)
{
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName); //don't forget the extension

    HttpPostedFileBaseDerived test = new HttpPostedFileBaseDerived(file.ContentLength, file.ContentType, (newFileName + ext), file.InputStream);
    return (HttpPostedFileBase)test; //cast it back to HttpPostedFileBase 
}
```

Once you are done you can `type cast` it back to `HttpPostedFileBase` so you wouldn't have to change any other code that you already have.

Hope this helps to anyone in the future. Also thanks to Manoj Choudhari for his answer, thanks to I learned of where not to look for the solution.

Comment: Renaming the uploaded file that's in memory without wasting resources on unnecessary saving it.

Comment: But why'd you override a class for that? Can't you keep a string containing the desired filename and pass that to the method that handles the file?

Comment: Surely, you can do it, but in some cases the code becomes messier this way, as now instead of passing a single thing around, you pass two. So it's nice to have an alternative that doesn't force you to change a whole lot of the other code down the chain just to rename some files.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:** NO

**Long Answer:**
You can rename a file only if file exists on File System.

The files uploaded are not files at all - when you access them using Request.Files.  They are streams.    The fileName property is readonly because of the same reason.

There is no name associated with stream.

As per documentation, FileName property

> Gets the fully qualified name of the file on the client.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to respond, you saved a lot of time for me by telling where I won't find the solution :)